# What is the best practice on cloning a resource with Backbone.js in a RESTFul application?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for a scenario where I need do clone a resource (a Request in this example) using Backbone.js and RESTful architecture.

When a user clone some resource a dialog should appear where he can type a new name for the Request and set a new DeadlineDate, all other fields must be cloned from the other Request. The name that appear on the dialog should be something like **Request Name (Clone 1)**, where the number should be the number of copies already created.

The code below is a representation of how I'm designing it:

```
var RequestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/path/to/request',
    idAttribute: "Id",
    defaults: {
        Name: '',
        DeadlineDate: '',
        // loads of other options
        Content: '',
        Documents: []
        TeamMembers: []
    }
})

// Request View
var RequestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .btn-clone': 'clone'
    },
    clone: function(e){
        var id = $(e.target).closest('.request').data('request-id'),
            referenceModel = new RequestModel({ Id: id  });

        // with the clone true param the server should append
        // to the Name of the Request: (Clone *Number*)
        referenceModel
            .on({ 'sync': this.renderCloneDialog }, this)
            .fetch({ data: { clone: true } });
    },
    renderCloneDialog: function(model){
        // create a brand new instance of the model
        // with the previous values
        var clonedRequest = model.toJSON();
            clonedModel = new RequestModel( _.omit(clonedRequest, 'Id')  );

        // send the cloned from id so the server use as reference
        clonedModel.set('ClonedFromRequestId', clonedRequest.get('Id'));

        var clonedRequestDialog = new CloneRequestDialogView({
            model: clonedModel
        });
    }
});

// Request View
var CloneRequestDialogView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // the method for saving will be just saving 
    saveClone: function(){
        // update data based on the form
        // and save the model
        this.model.save();
    }
});
```

This is the workflow on how the cloning works:

1. The user clicks on clone.
2. A request is made fetching the resource with the url param `clone: true`. This will return the Request name appending **Clone 'Clone Numnber'**.
3. A dialog will open where the user can input some data.
4. A new model will be created without Id and setting a new attribute with the parent Request. Ex.: `ClonedFromRequestId: 123`.
5. This new model is saved.

I don't know if this is the best practice for this scenario.